# Can I use TinyMce in Asp.Net MVC 5 with regular HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

The code I am talking about in my view bag goes like this

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Message</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="PostBody" placeholder="PostBody" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it is like the to make the Create work with two tables with ActionResult using a FormCollection.

Edit: regularly we would use TinyMce in a view bag with integrating the The script at the top after the view bag something like this :
 src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"

An then copy past a some code in it script to make it work.

And than after that in the default code generated by the project 
at the place we want to add  the Tiny MCE we replace the default 
 @Html.EditorFor by  @Html.TextAreaFor
And the result of that looks like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also we add in the class just before the row we want:  [AllowHtml]

But the way they teach me in class dosen't seem to work With the ActionResult in my controller in which I use a FormCollection.

So if I can use code like the second one with a FormCollection ( unless there is a way and I just don't know) How should I add Tiny MCE to the code like the first example if it can be done.

EDIT: Also I should have mention this before but I am using EntityFramwork 6 and Authentification , but not using Async Controller action.

I am kinda confuse went I search on google and I tried a lot. 
Maybe someone here can help me.

Comment: The answer is, of course you can use TinyMce with MVC 5. TinyMce runs on the client and MVC on the server. But you need to add some detail to your question because it is not possible to tell where you are stuck.

Comment: it looks like you need to study MVC concepts more before diving into this

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, My class is kinda rushed on this subject and not clear. We know what a Controller, Model and Views do and a little bit of coding in there and also how to use Linq and Lambda but that about it.
The best advice we got from our teacher to most of our question is Google... which is not a bad thing for specific things. But the concept other from what I mentioned before and how to code there is seriously 
lacking. 


I edited my reply, maybe it gave enough details this time

Comment: `[AllowHtml]` is applied to a property in a model, but if you using `FormCollection` (dreadful practice and should never be used) then your not binding to you model so the attribute is ignored. Replace `FormCollection` with the model that your using in the view.

Comment: -  Stephen Muecke
I see, so can you refer me to a good post or tutorial to how to make a Create using 2 tables at the same time ? That would really help.

Answer (score 0):

To begin I will show my entire section of my ActionResult.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection) 
    {

        string PostBody = collection["PostBody"];
        string SujetTitle = collection["SujetTitle"];   
        int CategoryID_FK = (int)Session["catid"];

        Sujet j = new Sujet()
        {
            SujetTitle = SujetTitle,
            CategoryID_FK = CategoryID_FK,
            PostBody = PostBody,
            SujetDateCreation = DateTime.Now
        };

        db.Sujets.Add(j);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Posts.Add(new Post() { SujetID_FK = j.SujetID, PostBody = PostBody });
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.CategoryID_FK = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryTitle", j.CategoryID_FK);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Categories");

    }
```

So in order to make this work I needed to add in the class if my EF-DataBase 
the part I wanted for the other table like so

```
    [AllowHtml]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }
```

the model I was using was the default 
And if I wanted to use the Razor in my Create View
I needed for it to appear in the Model like so

```
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Now back to my Controller, now that I added the  PostBody { get; set; } to my class I could do this part and now I can also add PostBody.

```
  Sujet j = new Sujet()
    {
        SujetTitle = SujetTitle,
        CategoryID_FK = CategoryID_FK,
        PostBody = PostBody,
        SujetDateCreation = DateTime.Now
    };
```

Now we say that the real value of the PostBody in the class is equal to   the one of PostBody in the collection in which has the value stored from what he got in the view,now the Values can by saved by two tables and we can use Razor with

```
@Html.TextAreaFor
```

So from now on you add the TinyMCE like you would normally do.

But there is one last catch, Like that I wont work if we go check-back my first code sample you need to add

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

And now it works !

Now I would like to comment something about o this situation. 
This is for a work assignment in my class. and the [ValidateInput(false)]
It the teacher how decided to teach it to us that way, to make up for is mistake of learning us to do a Create with two tables at the same time with a FormCollection and forgetting the fact that he required us to add TinyMCE in this work.

So I don't really not if it truly worthless but here it is anyway. 
If you know some tutorial on this topic or more please feel free to share them with me.I am always willing to learn more and getting better.